# Finding Days Difference on oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

Following SQL gives me invalid number error.

Please advise -

```
select 
  TRUNC(Sysdate-1) - TO_CHAR(TO_DATE("$25->$5 Date",'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS'), 'MM/DD/YYYY'),
  "$25->$5 Date"
from Conversion_Payer
Where "Benefit Converted" is not null 
  and "$25->$5 Date" is not null
```

Thank You!

Comment: This SQL worked for me  - select TRUNC(Sysdate-1) - TRUNC(TO_DATE("$25->$5 Date",'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS')),"$25->$5 Date"
from Conversion_Payer
Where "Benefit Converted" is not  null and "$25->$5 Date" is not null

Answer (score 0):

Huh; I initially thought that this isn't Oracle. Apparently, it *is*, but column names you use are more than awful. I suggest you get rid of those.

In order to get difference between two **DATE** datatype columns, you have to convert those that aren't DATEs. I presume that "$25->$5 Date" is a character so you'd then

```
select 
  TRUNC(Sysdate-1) - TO_DATE("$25->$5 Date",'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS') diff_in_days,
  "$25->$5 Date"
from Conversion_Payer
Where "Benefit Converted" is not null 
  and "$25->$5 Date" is not null
```

On the other hand, if "$25->$5 Date" is a `DATE` datatype, then simply subtract it from SYSDATE (i.e. no conversion is needed):

```
select 
  TRUNC(Sysdate-1) - "$25->$5 Date" diff_in_days
...
```

Comment: My Select statement is based off of CTE, my original table Column names are labelled appropriately. Thanks for the advise though.

Comment: You're welcome. Apart from the *naming issues*, did *date subtraction* part help?

Comment: Yes, suggested data subtraction part was helpful. Thanks again!

Comment: OK, I'm glad if it helped.